# Pytorch - Losses values much higher after loading models

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am working on this implementation of a GAN:

https://github.com/rishikksh20/hifigan-denoiser/blob/master/train.py

You can see there are a total of three neural networks, plus the optimizes defined using   `torch.optim.AdamW`.
It seems that, when loading both the networks and the optimizers using `load_state_dict`, the loss functions start from a much higher value.

Judging from some similar issues here on stackoverflow, this may be due to the learning rates or other parameters not being stored. However, the learning rate here is fixed. The loading operations seem all be correctly executed here. Can you spot the bug in the code?

Comment: Can you tr using the different save modules https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html. With the torch.save that saves the entire pickle this issue should not come

Comment: Hi, ```save_checkpoint()``` is a custom function here used for saving networks, optimizers and other variables. This is based on ```torch.save(obj, filepath)```.